# Can't push on a remote git branch in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, push, commit

I come to you because I have this really annoying issue. In Xcode, I deleted some files and now, when I want to push my sources, it says that I can't since there is some uncommitted change. The uncommitted change come from the deleted files (Xcode shows me these files marked with a "d").

My question is how I make my git repo sync with it so I can push my sources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to commit your changes before you push onto your remote.  If you go to your project directory, type:

`git status`

It should show you the files which have been deleted.  If it looks okay to you, type:

`git commit -a -m "your commit message here"`

Then you should be able to push to your remote repo:

`git push <remote> <remote_branch>`

Comment: Just to be sure, what -a means (I assume it will force to delete the deleted locally deleted files)? And so there is no way to do it using xCode (I don't know if you are familiar with it)

Comment: `-a` will stage and commit any modified or deleted files you see in `git status`.  Sorry not too familiar with the xcode git interface

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answer of triad:

1. Select your project in the Project Navigator
2. Select under the File menu->Source Control->Commit
3. Select under the File menu->Source Control->Push (if you want to push it to a remote repo)

On the Mac it helps to research the items under the menu bar, as the popup menu is not always populated fully.

Comment: No remote servers were showing when i need to push my code to git

Comment: In that case, either your project was not part of a git repository, or your Xcode is screwed up. Try quiting Xcode and re-opening the project.